# Big oh notation for heaps

Tags: algorithm

I am trying to understand big oh notations. Any help would be appreciated.

Say there is a program that creates a max heap and then pushes and removes the item.

Say there is n items.

To create a heap,it takes O(n) to heapify if you have read it into an array and then, heapifies it.
To push an item, it takes O(1) and to remove it, it takes O(1)
To heapify it after that, it takes log n for each remove and n log n for n items

So the big oh notation is O(n + n log n)
OR, is it O(n log n) only because we choose the biggest one.

Comment: `O(n + n log n) = O(n log n)`

Comment: From your answer, I understand that you always take the biggest.

Comment: yes you only consider the dominant term

Comment: Say, you run this l times. Is the big oh notation l(n log n). The book says that you could ignore the constant but if the constant is really big, can we leave it ?

Comment: if I is constant then you don't consider it. Only terms that depend on the input size are considered

Comment: If I write this, the total time is l(n log n). Is this fine ? I am not stating the the big O ? Thank you

Comment: If this is academic stuff then do not write I, or write then say that it is equivalent to the nlgn version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The complexity to heapify the new element in the heap is `O(logN)`, not `O(1)`(unless you use an [Fibonacci heap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_heap) which it seems is not the case).

Also there is no notation `O(N + NlogN)` as `NlogN` grows faster than `N` so this notation is simply written as `O(NlogN)`.

EDIT: The big-oh notation only describes the asymptotic behavior of a function, that is - how fast it grows. As you get close to infinity `2*f(x)` and `11021392103*f(x)` behave similarly and that is why when writing big-oh notation, we ignore any constants in front of the function.

Comment: Sorry, you mentioned that "Only terms that depend on the input size are considered". Say, that n is somehow involve, do you mean that n(nlog n) is fine then

Comment: @user1952529 I am sorry I do not understand what comment means.

Comment: thanks a lot for looking into this..i am confused when i should add the constants to the big oh notation. perreal mentioned that only terms that depend on the input size are considered. What does this mean?

Comment: izomorphius, sorry, thanks for replying..Say, you need to run this program n times. Would the big oh notation be n(n log n) then.

Comment: If the number of times you run the program is not a constant but is the same n that is present in your input, then yes, the complexity of running it n times would be `O(n*n*log(n))`

Comment: thanks for replying. say the program runs once 5 times and another time is runs 6 times and the other times it runs 10 times. so, this is not a constant. lets call this p (instead of n). the big oh notation is then O(p*n log (n))..thanks a lot..sorry for the questions..

Comment: If that p may change i.e. is a variable than yes that is the complexity. If p is a constant though(i.e. each time you run this p will be the same), than your complexity will not depend on it.

Answer (score 0):

Formally speaking, `O(N + N log N)` is equivalent to `O(N log N)`.

That said, it's assumed that there are coefficients buried in each of these, ala: `O( aN + bN log(cN) )`. If you have very large `N` values, these coefficients become unimportant and the algorithm is bounded only by its largest term, which, in this case, is `log(N)`.

But it doesn't mean the coefficients are *entirely* unimportant. This is why in discussions of graph algorithms you'll often see authors say something like "the [Floyd-Warshall algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm) runs in O(N^3) time, but has small coefficients".

If we could somehow write O(0.5N^3) in this case, we would. But it turns out that the coefficients vary depending on how you implement an algorithm and which computer you run it on. Thus, we settle for asymptotic comparisons, not necessarily because it is the best way, but because there isn't really a good alternative.

You'll also see things like "Worst-case: O(N^2), Average case: O(N)". This is an attempt to capture how the behavior of the algorithm varies with the input. Often times, presorted or random inputs can give you that average case, whereas an evil villain can construct inputs that produce the worst case.

Ultimately, what I am saying is this: `O(N + N log N)=O(N log N)`. This is true, and it's the right answer for your homework.  But we use this big-O notation to communicate and, in the fullness of time, you may find situations where you feel that `O(N + N log N)` is more expressive, perhaps if your algorithm is generally used for small `N`. In this case, do not worry so much about the formalism - just be clear about what it is you are trying to convey with it.